# equivalent of filter_var($some_variable, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)

Tags: php, filter, htmlpurifier

I filter my variable like so

`filter_var($some_variable, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)`

Using [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org), how do I filter the variable? tried,

```
$htmlpurifier->purify($some_varable);
```

But Acunetix says 'cross site scripting detected'.

How do you use filter_var in HTMLPurifier?.

Answer (score 0):

From the website there is this example:
    `<?php
    require_once '/path/to/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
    ?>`